# PIC18F4550's internal oscillator block power consumption

Tags: microcontroller, pic, microchip

I started learning the PIC18F4550 recently, and I came across the internal oscillator segment where an 8 MHz internal oscillator source is divided into multiple clock signals of different frequencies. Does dividing the clock source save any power?
(Because the oscillator source is the same, the power consumption should be the same or maybe more due to the frequency divider. However, my instructor indicated that the answer to this has something to do with delays, and I can not seem to figure out what it is)

Comment: No, dividing the clock source does not save power. It is used for slow peripherals like a UART with only 115.2 kBaud.

Comment: Are you talking about the internal oscillator frequency selection (8 frequencies to choose from)? In that case: Running at lower frequencies does save power.

Comment: @StefanWyss alright, thanks for the answer!

Comment: @Unimportant Yeah the 8 frequency options that go into the selecting multiplexer. But how does it save power when there’s a single source of 8MHz. Can’t seem to wrap my head around this.

Comment: @ObedA. The transistors such as those inside a PIC use very little power when fixed in a certain state (on or off). The bulk of the power is consumed during switching from one state to the other. By running the PIC at a lower speed less of these switching events happen in a given amount of time, thereby consuming less power.

Comment: @Unimportant - not necessarily, race to sleep often the better choice to save power. In terms of dynamic power, yes, there might be some power saving available from clocking lower, but it wouldn't be my first place to look.

Comment: @awjlogan I don't think that's relevant here. We're not looking at power required to perform a certain task but simply if running at a lower clockspeed consumes less power per unit of time. It does, and if you look at the datasheet figures, significantly.

Comment: @Unimportant - it's always relevant when developing for low power systems. From the datasheet, 1 MHz -> 4 MHz increases current by 2.3X, but the same work takes 1/4 of the time. Dropping to IDLE (not even sleep), the current is the same (0.52 mA ish) for both frequencies (internal clock gating). But, fair enough, the question is probably more about clock trees but it's still relevant information, especially given the IDLE state power.

Comment: Choosing a lower frequency output from the multiplexer does not affect the power consumption of the oscillator, it reduces the power consumption of all the other modules which are driven by that lower frequency clock signal they're now receiving.